# webrtc-conferencing-1v3-connectionFactory.dispose()-crashes

Tags: android, webrtc

I am trying to create a 1v3 or 4v4 conferencing(whatever you call it) android app, i have successfully connected 4 people together using webrtc and socket.io.
But when i disconnect one of the users i get webrtc native crash

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xb8 in tid 17650 (Thread-648)
```

Same code works in `moto c` but crashes on other devices.

webrtc version used - `compile 'io.pristine:libjingle:9694@aar'`

```
 onDisconnect(){
   if (null != peerConnection2) {
        peerConnection2.removeStream(localMediaStream);
        peerConnection2.close();
        peerConnection2 = null;
    }
    if (null != peerConnection3) {
        peerConnection3.dispose();
        peerConnection3 = null;
    }
    if (null != localVideoSource) {
        localVideoSource.dispose();
        localVideoSource = null;
    }
    if (null != peerConnectionFactory) {
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);

        peerConnectionFactory.dispose();  <<<<--- THIS IS WHERE THE APP CRASHES.
        peerConnectionFactory = null;
    }
}
```

I am not sure if updating the version will help me with this bug, even if i go for updating it to new version, i am unable to find any proper documentation or blog related to it, it'll be great if you can point me to any known link(blog/documentaion) for latest version of libjingle.

Comment: any luck in resolving issue coz i am stuck in same issue?

Comment: @AdeelTurk - yes, i did find a workaround, are you using the same webrtc version ?

Comment: try this onDisconnect :

`public void onDisconnect(View v) {
        peerConnection.close();
        peerConnection = null;
        peerConnection2.close();
        peerConnection2 = null;
        peerConnection3.close();
        peerConnection3 = null;
        socket.disconnect();
        //socket.off();
        finish();
    }`

Comment: @Gurvnder Thanks alot i figured it out somehow :)

Comment: @AdeelTurk - good to hear that. If your solution is different please mention it atleast in comments, Thank you.

Comment: i had a different scenario, actually it was many to one communication and the same time while during tat communication that one to whom others are connected can also communicate withe any one (one to one) , in short its was many to one and one to one video calling parallel , and if one disconnects other should not be interrupted     ,, a long story to tell

Comment: sounds like video streaming(broadcasting). Anyway best of luck.

Comment: yeah sort of we can say that broadcasting pus one to one video call  
Thanks

Comment: I'm using webrtc implementation within Kotlin by adding **implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.22672'** and facing this exact issue. @Gurvinder.Techwin you're not calling *dispose()* on your peerConnectionFactory, isn't that necessary?