# Fatal signal6 during disposing PeerConnection WebRTC

Tags: android, webrtc

I am using `WebRTC` for voice calling everything work fine. When Call hangUp i am disposing the `PeerConnection` as follows before finishing Call `Activity` .

```
 executor.execute(() -> {
        if (peerConnectionFactory != null) {
            peerConnectionFactory.dispose();
            peerConnectionFactory=null;
        }
        if (localPeer != null) {
            localPeer.dispose();
            localPeer=null;
        }
    });
```

I am getting fatal-signal-6. I have read [what-is-fatal-signal-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693887/what-is-fatal-signal-6-in-android-logcat) . Its says Do not block the UI thread, this can cause a SIGABRT as the OS will kill a non-responsive app . But i am calling it on non Ui thread and still getting the issue.

> Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00007e2f (code=-6), thread 32390 (worker_thread)

Please look into issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing wrong during closing the `peerConnection` . Correct flow of closing connection is below.

```
 executor.execute(() -> {
            if (peerConnectionFactory != null) {
                peerConnectionFactory.stopAecDump();
            }
            if (localPeer != null) {
                localPeer.dispose();
                localPeer = null;
            }
            if (peerConnectionFactory != null) {
                peerConnectionFactory.dispose();
                peerConnectionFactory = null;
            }
            PeerConnectionFactory.stopInternalTracingCapture();
            PeerConnectionFactory.shutdownInternalTracer();
        });
```

Comment: I tried it your way but I'm still getting a **Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xb8 in tid 26448 (Thread-13148)** when calling peerConnectionFactory.dispose() the only difference I can see with your code is that I'm using Kotlin and my peerConnectionFactory is declared as **var peerConnectionFactory: PeerConnectionFactory? = null** so I need the !! operator to access it... Any clues? Do I actually need to call *dispose()* on my peerConnectionFactory?

Comment: Found another thread facing my same situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169413/webrtc-conferencing-1v3-connectionfactory-dispose-crashes), although it has not ben answered yet it gets the exact same error message...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I called the 'release' function twice in parallel.
This caused the crash. Once the two threads were synced, the crash went away.